# Count Positive and negative numbers

Tags: java

```
public class Exercise_442 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int count=0;
    int positive=0;
    int negative =0;
    int nums=0;
    int sum=0;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Pleaes enter a positive or negative integer");
    nums = keyboard.nextInt();


    while(nums!=0){
        sum+=nums;
        System.out.println("Plese enter a positive or negative integer");
        nums = keyboard.nextInt();

        if(nums<0)
            negative++;

         if (nums>0)
            positive++;

    }
    System.out.println("The sum of these numbers is " +sum);
     System.out.println("The amount of negative numbers here is " + negative);
      System.out.println("The amount of positive numbers here is " + positive);
    }
  }
```

I need to count the positive and negative numbers here when I enter them. It displays these when the user inputs 0. It counts the negative numbers ok and gets the sum but I don't know why it falls short of one number when it counts the positive integers?

Answer (score 3):

Your first nums is ignored for +/- when you enter the while loop for the first time.

Let's say you enter 1 as `nums`. It'll add 1 to the sums and then ask for a new input without evaluating > or <.

Move your if statements above the `nums = keyboard.nextInt();` in the while loop.

```
    while(nums!=0){
        sum+=nums;

        //moved everything up before we pull nextInt
        if(nums<0)
            negative++;

         if (nums>0)
            positive++;

        System.out.println("Plese enter a positive or negative integer");
        nums = keyboard.nextInt();

    }
```

Comment: The second `nums = keyboard.nextInt();` that is.

Comment: @btrs20 Thanks. I added the entire method to my answer to make it clearer.